# Antlr4: extraneous input in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have problem running input stream for my grammar, here is part of my grammar

```
expression  
:  .... 
|   ( '+' | '-' | '&' |) expression
|   expression ('+'|'-') expression
   ....
;
```

when input stream like 2+2-2 or (2+2+2)-2, error occurs

```
line 10:30 extraneous input '-2' expecting {',', '^',...}
```

why my grammar can not distinguish between -2 and 2-2 ?
anyone help me please !

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have written your lexer in such a way that `-2` results in a single token. Instead of handling negative numbers in this way, treat `-` as a unary operator and allow your parser handle the negation operation. If you try to handle negative numbers directly in the lexer, input such as `2-2` will be sent to the parser as 2 consecutive number tokens (`2` followed by `-2`) instead of the desired 3 tokens (`2`, `-`, `2`).

Comment: sorry to say, but i just copy part of java.g4 (expression rule only) from antlr v4 example book. can you give me example to solve that ?

Comment: ok, i know what you mean, because  i added prefix at                  DECIMAL_LITERAL
    : ('-')? ('0'|'1'..'9' '0'..'9'*) IntegerTypeSuffix? 
    ;                                                                      thank you sam  .